# The Middle Way in practical life

Tags: sutras, middle-way

Are there any sutras or parables where Buddha applies the middle way, not to the self or to abstract metaphysical principles, but to concrete conflicts in practical life?

Answer (score 9):

There is a large body of texts of discourses of the Buddha touching on lay life issues. Below, I paste a (probably not exhaustive) list of suttas compiled by a user from [dhammalwheel forum](http://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=259). There's also an upcoming book from Bhikkhu Bodhi presenting a collection of suttas of discourses of the Buddha dealing with lay life themes: [The Buddha's Teachings on Social and Communal Harmony: An Anthology of Discourses from the Pali Canon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1614293554).

---

> DN 31: Sigalovada Sutta — To Sigala/The Layperson's Code of Discipline
> https://suttacentral.net/en/dn31
>
> MN 14: Cula-dukkhakkhandha Sutta — The Lesser Mass of Stress
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.014.than.html
>
> MN 41: Saleyyaka Sutta — The Brahmans of Sala
> https://suttacentral.net/en/mn41
>
> MN 52: Atthakanagara Sutta — To the Man from Atthakanagara
> https://suttacentral.net/en/mn52
>
> MN 53: Sekha-patipada Sutta — The Practice for One in Training
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.053.than.html
>
> MN 54: Potaliya Sutta — To Potaliya
> https://suttacentral.net/en/mn54
>
> MN 56. Upāli, the Householder
> https://suttacentral.net/en/mn56
>
> MN 57: Kukkuravatika Sutta — The Dog-duty Ascetic
> https://suttacentral.net/en/mn57
>
> MN 58: Abhaya Sutta — To Prince Abhaya (On Right Speech)
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.058.than.html
>
> MN 59: Bahuvedaniya Sutta — Many Things to be Experienced/The Many Kinds of Feeling
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.059.nypo.html
>
> MN 60: Apannaka Sutta — A Safe Bet
> https://suttacentral.net/en/mn60
>
> MN 97: Dhanañjani Sutta — To Dhanañjani
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.097.than.html
>
> MN 99:  To the Brahmin Subha
> http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/2Majjhima-Nikaya/Majjhima2/099-subha-e1.html
>
> MN 143: Anathapindikovada Sutta — Instructions to Anathapindika
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.143.than.html
>
> SN 3.19: Aputtaka Sutta — Heirless (1)
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.019.than.html
>
> SN 3.20: Aputtaka Sutta — Heirless (2)
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.020.than.html
>
> SN 22.1: Nakulapita Sutta — To Nakulapita
> https://suttacentral.net/en/sn22.1
>
> SN 22.3: Haliddakani Sutta — To Haliddakani
> https://suttacentral.net/en/sn22.3
>
> SN 22.80: Pindolya Sutta — Almsgoers
> https://suttacentral.net/en/sn22.80
>
> SN 41.3: Isidatta Sutta — About Isidatta
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn41/sn41.003.than.html
>
> SN 41.4: Mahaka Sutta — About Mahaka
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn41/sn41.004.than.html
>
> SN 41.6: Kamabhu Sutta — With Kamabhu (On the Cessation of Perception & Feeling)
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn41/sn41.006.than.html
>
> SN 41.7: Godatta Sutta — To Godatta (On Awareness-release)
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn41/sn41.007.than.html
>
> SN 41.10: Gilana Sutta — Sick (Citta the Householder's Last Hours)
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn41/sn41.010.than.html
>
> SN 47.29: Sirivaddha
> https://suttacentral.net/en/sn47.29
>
> SN 47.30: Manadinna
> https://suttacentral.net/en/sn47.30
>
> SN 55.30: Licchavi Sutta — To the Licchavi
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn55/sn55.030.than.html
>
> 107. Discourse to a Householder
>      https://suttacentral.net/en/sa107
>
> AN 3.65: Kalama Sutta — To the Kalamas/The Buddha's Charter of Free Inquiry
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an3.65
>
> AN 3.66: Salha Sutta — To Salha
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an3.66
>
> AN 3.70: Muluposatha Sutta — The Roots of the Uposatha
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an3.70
>
> AN 3.92: Urgent
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an3.92
>
> AN 4.32: Sangaha Sutta — The Bonds of Fellowship
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.32
>
> AN 4.55: Samajivina Sutta — Living in Tune
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.55
>
> AN 4.60: The Layperson’s Proper Practice
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.60
>
> AN 4.62: Anana Sutta — Debtless
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.62
>
> AN 4.258: Kula Sutta — On Families
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.258
>
> AN 5.38: Saddha Sutta — Conviction
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.38
>
> AN 5.41: Adiya Sutta — Benefits to be Obtained (from Wealth)
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.41
>
> AN 5.43: Wished for
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.43
>
> AN 5.57: Upajjhatthana Sutta — Subjects for Contemplation
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.57
>
> AN 5.175: Candala Sutta — The Outcaste
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.175
>
> AN 5.176: Piti Sutta — Rapture
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.176
>
> AN 5.177: Vanijja Sutta — Business (Wrong Livelihood)
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.177
>
> AN 5.179: Gihi Sutta — The Householder
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.179
>
> AN 5.180: Gavesin Sutta — About Gavesin
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.180
>
> AN 6.16: Nakula’s Parents
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an6.16
>
> AN 8.25: Mahanama Sutta — Being a Lay Buddhist
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an8.25
>
> AN 8.26: Jivaka Sutta — To Jivaka (On Being a Lay Follower)
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an8.26
>
> AN 8.43: Visakhuposatha Sutta — The Discourse to Visakha on the Uposatha with the Eight Practices
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an8.43
>
> AN 8.54: Vyagghapajja (Dighajanu) Sutta — Conditions of Welfare/ To Dighajanu
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an8.54
>
> AN 10.92: Vera Sutta — Animosity
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an10.92
>
> AN 10.93: Ditthi Sutta — Views
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an10.93
>
> AN 10.94: Vajjiya Sutta — About Vajjiya
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an10.94
>
> AN 11.11: Mahanama Sutta — To Mahanama (1)
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an11.11
>
> AN 11.12: Mahanama Sutta — To Mahanama (2)
> https://suttacentral.net/en/an11.12
>
> Dhammapada — The Path of Dhamma
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/index.html
>
> Ud 8.8: Visakha Sutta — To Visakha
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.8.08.than.html
>
> Ud 2.5: Upasaka Sutta — The Lay Follower
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.2.05.than.html
>
> Ud 2.6: Gabbhini Sutta — The Pregnant Woman
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.2.06.than.html
>
> Ud 2.7: Ekaputta Sutta — The Only Son
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.2.07.than.html
>
> Ud 2.9: Visakha Sutta — To Visakha
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.2.09.than.html
>
> Ud 5.6: Sona Sutta — About Sona
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.5.06.than.html
>
> Sn 1.2: Dhaniya Sutta — Dhaniya the Cattleman
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.1.02.than.html
>
> Sn 2.1: Ratana Sutta — Treasures
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.2.01.piya.html
>
> Sn 2.4: Maha-mangala Sutta — Protection
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.2.04.nara.html
>
> Sn 2.14: Dhammika Sutta — Dhammika
> http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.2.14.irel.html

Comment: Wow. Maybe somewhat fewer references would be more in keeping with the spirit of the question? :)

Answer (score 5):

This web book called [Constitution for Living](https://www.mahidol.ac.th/budsir/Contents.html) summarises the Buddha's teachings for laypeople.

My selection for the list in the other post is:

> AN 3.65: Kalama Sutta — To the Kalamas/The Buddha's Charter of Free Inquiry
>   https://suttacentral.net/en/an3.65
>
> Sn 2.4: Maha-mangala Sutta — Protection
>   http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.2.04.piya.html
>
> [SN 55.7 Veludvareyya Sutta - Discourse to the People of Bamboo Gate](http://www.buddhismwithoutboundaries.com/showthread.php?213-The-Buddha-s-Unshakable-Ethics-the-Discourse-to-the-People-of-Bamboo-Gate)
>
> AN 4.55: Samajivina Sutta — Living in Tune
>   https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.55
>
> AN 4.62: Anana Sutta — Debtless
>   https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.62
>
> AN 5.177: Vanijja Sutta — Business (Wrong Livelihood)
>   https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.177
>
> AN 4.258: Kula Sutta — On Families
>   https://suttacentral.net/en/an4.258
>
> DN 31: Sigalovada Sutta — To Sigala/The Layperson's Code of Discipline
>   http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html
>
> AN 5.57: Upajjhatthana Sutta — Subjects for Contemplation
>   https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.57
>
> AN 8.25: Mahanama Sutta — Being a Lay Buddhist
>   https://suttacentral.net/en/an8.25

Comment: Thank you for taking a more moderate approach to answering!

Answer (score 0):

The Middle Way is applied in the Buddha's early life story (told especially in Majjhima Nikaya 26 & 36) in a way that is directly demonstrated rather than abstracted from its context as doctrine. The Buddha leaves the Palace because the environment there is one that assumes the ultimate value of its relative social and political values (also associated with hedonism), and the 'Three Considerations' of Old Age, Sickness and Death make him aware of the inadequacy of those values. He then seeks out two teachers in the forest - Alara Kalama and Udaka Ramaputta - both of whom claim to have final answers in the meditative states they have reached - but he is not satisfied by either of these, nor by the asceticism he then engages in. He discovers the Middle Way as a result of recalling the earlier more embodied awareness of a jhana experience under a rose-apple tree in his childhood, showing that the Middle Way is rooted in acceptance of the body. The Palace and the Forest each represent absolute but opposing beliefs, each of which the Buddha learns the limitations of. He learns from both contexts, but also maintains a critical sense of their limitations. The key features of this story are also central to the practice of the Middle Way: expecting to find meaningful information from every new view but also maintaining a critical perspective on it, trying to limit our dualistic oscillations, and gradually developing a more adequate, mature, and integrated response to experience.

Answer (score 0):

The eightfold path. It is the path that describes the middle way ie not taking extremes. Taking baby steps to enlightenment.